# Upgrading from Fedora 11 to Fedora 12 Using preupgrade 0MB More Space Required

Tags: fedora-12

I was trying to update to Fedora 12 this morning and the upgrader told me that I needed 18 more megs in partition /mnt/sysimage/boot.  I got rid of some old kernel files and tried again, now it tells me I need 0 megs more.  I got rid of the memcheck files which at least equal 1 meg (to account for some rounding inconsistencies)

It's still not installing, anybody see this themselves?

Is my boot partition just not writable?

Would it help it somehow increase it's size?

Can I make a new boot partition just for upgrading?

Would it help to install using a CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a known bug.

http://www.mail-archive.com/fedora-devel-list@redhat.com/msg10793.html

http://www.mail-archive.com/fedora-list@redhat.com/msg57468.html

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PreUpgrade#Not_enough_space_in_.2Fboot

Now it's a better known Bug!

Yay SuperUser.com!